# Is there a stable, production ready library for ruby for websockets?

Tags: ruby, websocket, em-websocket, cramp

I've been using Socket.io with node.js for some time, but I'd really love to do this in Ruby. There seem to be some projects available, but most of them are dead, namely:

- [danthes](http://phenomena.github.com/danthes/) - fork of Ryan Bates' `private_pub`
- [cramp](https://github.com/lifo/cramp) - no activity for the past 9 months
- [socket.io-ruby](https://github.com/dkastner/socket.io-ruby) - no activity for the past 11 months

the only project I was able to find is [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket), which however is very low level and doesn't have any client side library.

Am I missing some project or librarly, or is there really no way to do WebSockets with Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [faye-websocket](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/websockets.html)? I never used it tough but I *trust* the author.

Answer (score 3):

At [Pusher](http://pusher.com) we use and contribute to [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket).

On the client we then have our own Pusher JavaScript library which uses [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) for Flash fallback.

Some more options, including an open source self-install version of Pusher (not by Pusher) are available via the [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide)